# Missing common classes on a KMM project when integrated in an Android App as a Gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, git-submodules, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I have an existing Android app where I like to integrate a KMM library project as a git submodule. We want to integrate a git submodule on local builds and using a maven repository dependency on CI builds.

To achieve this, I added the directory of the submodule in my `settings.gradle` via `includeBuild` and substitute all dependencies of a specific module:

```
includeBuild('my-kmm-library-project') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.example.any-kmm-artifact:any') using project(':any')
    }
}
```

Adding

```
implementation 'com.example.any-kmm-artifact:any:1.0.0'
```

to my application `build.gradle` file allows access to all classes and packages in the android sourceset int the submodule `/my-kmm-library-project/any/src/androidMain`. But I have no option to import "classes" from the `commonMain` sourceset. I already tried to let `androidMain` depend on `commonMain.`

kmm/build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
val androidMain by getting {
    dependsOn(commonMain)
    ...

}
```

This doesn't lead to any success.

I also tried to add a `jvm()` target on KMM project and let `jvmMain` depend on `androidMain`, but this produces compile error, cause the Android SDK classes cannot be resolved.

I think the main problem is that, the classes are just compiled into the aar which can be assembled. But the module is integrated as a gradle project implementation.

Is there a KMM option to compile "common classes" and access them through a gradle module?

Comment: Hello, @elcolto! This seems like a problem caused by the current state of the kotlin-multiplatform Gradle plugin. Consider filing an issue at https://kotl.in/issue.

Comment: Related Kotlin Issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52356

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue.... in my case, i'm able to access the common module classes... but it throws a error like no classdef found for ContentNegotiation... when i check in the project view seems like the ktor-content-negotiation library alone not downloaded ... do you have any fix for this?